# How to develop a prediction model based on correlation in R?

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, predictive-models, prediction

I have two sets of data, say sales and profit, and I have calculated the correlation between these two data over different months using `R`. So currently I have somethings like this:

```
Month       | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | ....
sales       |  X  |  Y  |  Z  |  P  | ....
profit      |  A  |  B  |  C  |  D  | ....
correlation | .1  | .35 | .28 | -.47| ....
```

This correlation calculation has been done over period of years and now I want to develop a prediction model which can provide me prediction for coming months of coming years,say what will be the profit for month of Aug 2014? How can I develop such a prediction model and what else, apart from what I have as of now, will I need to develop the prediction model? I am new to statistics and predictive analysis and thus if anyone could provide me a guide of required steps and some info about how can I do those steps then it would be very helpful for me to get the understanding also.

Thanks in advance.

**NOTE:** If I could get help in respect to some non parametric bayesian method then it will be great.

Comment: Is the `correlation` variable the correlation between sales and profit, or the period between months?

Comment: @gmacfarlane the correlation is the correlation between sales and profit for each month

Comment: and based on this correlation I want to do predictions for future months of different years.